# JSF request attribute

Tags: jsf, attributes, request

I am using JSF 1.2. I have a page with a button. The action hooked to the button adds a request attribute to the request object and navigates to page2. On page2 I try to retrieve that attribute with #{requestScope.attr}. But this doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently page2 was requested by a different HTTP request. That can happen if you have sent a redirect instead of a forward when the action method is finished. For example, by calling `ExternalContext#redirect()` in the action method or by adding `<redirect />` to the navigation case. A redirect basically instructs the browser to create a brand new HTTP request.

That said, I wonder how it's useful to explicitly set a request attribute if you're already using JSF. Just assign the desired data as a property of the current bean (which I assume to be just request scoped).

```java
private String foo; // +getter

public String submit() {
    foo = "some value";
    return "nextpage";
}
```

This way it's just available by `#{bean.foo}` in the next page.

```html
<h:outputText value="The value is: #{bean.foo}" />
```